# I have this ldap code and i only want users from a specific group (cn) to be able to login

Tags: php, ldap, ldap-query

Here is my code

```
    if ($bind) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $username['username'];
        header("Location: /Login/Homepage.php");

        //@ldap_close($ldap);
    }else {
   $errMSG = "Wrong Credentials, Try again...";
  }
```

can you please help me what to add in my code to only let users from a specific group (cn) to access the homepage. thanks!

Comment: I'm not really getting what you try to accieve. When I call ```/Login/Homepage.php``` on your server then I'm logged in? Because I can call that from anywhere, can't I? If not we need a bit more information on what you do to help you fix the issue. A simple "doesn't work, please help" ... well... doesn't work ;)

Comment: i am sorry. i just realized that some parts of my code is irrelevant to what i want to achieve. i have edited the question to be more clear. thanks!

Comment: When you have a successful bind, you are REDIRECTING users to ```/Login/Homepage.php```. That's a different page that can be called *without* having to login first! So users can point their browsers to ```/Login/Homepage.php``` without seeing the login-page before. And as it's a redirect the browser shows that URI in the location-bar so you can even bookmark it and then bypass "login"

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything with the result (exept of sorting which you shouldn't use `ldap_sort` for anymore). You have a result-handle in $result and that's it… Perhaps you should check out https://gist.github.com/heiglandreas/5689592 and see whether that helps you a bit more.